# How to solved error executing procedure in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Just started with the issue of procedures in **PL/SQL** Oracle and I am presenting a problem at the time of executing it, it indicates the error `ORA-00984`

The following is the code of the procedure I am performing

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_FILEUPLOAD_XML IS

            BEGIN 
                INSERT INTO SPRCMNT (
                             SPRCMNT_CMTT_CODE,
                             SPRCMNT_TEXT,
                             SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR)
                                    VALUES(P_CMTT_CODE,
                                           P_TEXT,
                                           P_TEXT_NAR); 
                 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN    
                 COMMIT;
            END;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Error:' || SQLERRM);       
            DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(l_loc);
            --dbms_output.put_line('P_RET_VAL:' || P_RET_VAL);    
    END;
```

This is the error when saving my procedure

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

I do not know if I am missing any declaration of variables or something, as I say I am just beginning with the issue of procedures and request your help.

Comment: Well, for starters, you haven't declared your variables that are referenced in your VALUES clause.  Where to you expect the compiler to do get them? Next, your WHEN OTHERS THEN COMMIT will simply swallow any errors and not report them, so you will have no idea when it fails at run time. Next, your outer WHEN OTHERS, is closing something that was never opened. Plus you are depending on DBMS_OUTPUT to do your reporting, but it is up to the executing client to actuall read dbms_output and present it -- which is not a good expectation from a PL/SQL procedure

Comment: Where in the procedure do I declare the variables?

Comment: Where in the procedure do I declare the variables? This is basic PL/SQL coding.  Have you even looked at the reference manual?  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm

Comment: You started this thread asking for syntax help.  Now you are asking for performance help, which is entirely different and implies you've solved your syntax issues.  You replied too quickly to have actually looked up the syntax issues in the cited reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208863/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-edstevens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use this method to insert into your table. Where you assign the variables inside the procedure

   ```
   create or replace PROCEDURE P_FILEUPLOAD_XML AS

     -- Declare the Variables
     P_CMTT_CODE VARCHAR2(200);
     P_TEXT VARCHAR2(200);
     P_TEXT_NAR VARCHAR2(200);

   BEGIN 

     -- Set variables with a value
     P_CMTT_CODE := 'VALUE 1';
     P_TEXT      := 'VALUE 2';
     P_TEXT_NAR  := 'VALUE 3';

     -- Insert into table
     INSERT INTO SPRCMNT
     ( SPRCMNT_CMTT_CODE,
       SPRCMNT_TEXT,
       SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR )
     VALUES  
     ( P_CMTT_CODE,
       P_TEXT,
       P_TEXT_NAR );


   EXCEPTION

     -- Catch error and log result
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       dbms_output.put_line('Error:' || SQLERRM);           

   END;
   ```
2. Or alternative pass the variables into the procedure. both will achieve the same result

   ```
   create or replace PROCEDURE P_FILEUPLOAD_XML(P_CMTT_CODE VARCHAR2,P_TEXT VARCHAR2, P_TEXT_NAR VARCHAR2)   AS


   BEGIN        

     -- Insert into table
     INSERT INTO SPRCMNT
     ( SPRCMNT_CMTT_CODE,
       SPRCMNT_TEXT,
       SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR )
     VALUES  
     ( P_CMTT_CODE,
       P_TEXT,
       P_TEXT_NAR );


   EXCEPTION

     -- Catch error and log result
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       dbms_output.put_line('Error:' || SQLERRM);           

   END;
   ```

   -- How to run procedure

   ```
   BEGIN

     P_FILEUPLOAD_XML('VALUE1' , 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3');

   END;
   ```